# NewRelic and user privacy policy

Tags: privacy, newrelic

If running NewRelic (with and without Realtime User Monitoring) what do I need to state in a privacy policy on a website for users? ie what information is collected, what cookies (if any) are set. Security of their data, aggregate vs individual.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

New Relic has doc covering these issues in some detail. You can read specifically about [Privacy with real-user monitoring](https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/features/security-with-real-user-monitoring), [What types of cookies New Relic sets](https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/subscriptions/new-relic-cookies), and [some broader information about security and privacy](https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/subscriptions/security).

The gist, I think, is given in the Real User Monitoring article:

> New Relic's Real User Monitoring (RUM) feature details the time it takes for your users' browsers to load your webpages, where they come from, and what browsers they use. To protect your web application's security and your users' privacy, New Relic only collects performance data with RUM. New Relic does not collect any data used or stored by the monitored app.

The data collected from your application server might also capture user data in the form of transaction traces. You can [use obfuscation to block user data from appearing in your traces](https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/traces/security-options-for-transaction-traces).

Note that both RUM and transaction traces are optional features.

For further details about privacy, I'd recommend [contacting New Relic directly](http://support.newrelic.com).